# Make `rake test` invoke `bundle exec rake test` automatically

Tags: ruby, bundler

My `Rakefile` requires certain dependencies that are installed with bundler. And therefore, the correct way to run my `Rakefile` is using `bundle exec rake`.

However, I'm sure one day somebody will accidentally run it with `rake`. So we have added to the top:

```
abort('fatal: Please run this using `bundle exec rake`') unless ENV["BUNDLE_BIN_PATH"]
```

However it would be a lot more helpful if the script instead reran itself as `bundle exec rake` with any additional command line arguments. How do I do this? Bonus points if it fails gracefully when `bundler` is not installed.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but there is never a good reason to `bundle exec`. Look into using RVM or rbenv and gemsets and your life will be much easier.

Comment: @JimStewart If you enjoy swimming upstream, Ruby probably isn't for you. Even the ruby managers you recommend disagree with you.

Comment: @JimStewart thanks for sharing the controversial thought. Could you point me to a good starting point to learn more about this?

Comment: To be clear, I am interested in helping other people that run my project. So answers that change my workflow will not help people that want to run this project.

Answer (score 1):

Use [binstubs](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/use-bundlers-binstubs):

1. Run `bundle binstubs rake` in the project root
2. Use `bin/rake` instead of `rake`

You no longer need to worry about typing `bundle exec` before your command. Any setup needed can be done without invoking anything manually on your command line. You can easily modify the binstub file, and it's project-specific.

Finally, if it's really too much to type `bin/rake`, you can alias something shorter, like `brake` or if you want to live on the edge, `alias rake='bin/rake'`.

Answer (score 0):

I think @coreyward has the answer, but if you get into a jam you could always `alias rake='bundle exec rake'` but that will probably get you into trouble another day.